# Is it important to measure the maximum voltage of the battery?

Tags: voltage, batteries, led, current, resistors

I have two LEDs and three batteries:

[image]

The typical voltage of one LED is 1.7V.  The maximum is 2V (there is no data about the initial voltage) within 700mA.

The nominal voltage of one battery is 1.2V.  The battery capacity is 780mAh.

When charging to full, the voltage goes up to 1.42V.

All I need is to link three batteries in series with two LEDs in series with suitable a resistance

- 3*1.2 =3.6V for nominal voltage of the battery
- 3*1.42=4.26V for maximum voltage of battery
- 3.6÷2 =1.8 when nominal voltage is on the LED
- 4.26÷2=2.13 wich is above the maximum voltage of a single LED

Is it OK if I just choose the resistance depending on the typical voltage of the LED and the nominal voltage of the battery, ignoring the maximum voltage of the battery?

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic. Click on edit and then the schematic symbol. You can draw it there.

Comment: @winny I cant because its not available on touch device (i will put a picture)

Comment: You have to choose series resistor according the Led current (from datasheet). Calculate with max voltage of batteries to not overdrive the Leds when batt. are fully charged. Btw, after you connect some load to fully charged battery the voltage decreases to about 1.35V (probably most accurate value for calculation).

Comment: Do you know the current it need? If not, start from a larger resistor, like 1kohm, slowly decrease it to find the resistor value you need.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický so when i need to chose resistance i chose it depending on the max voltage of the battery? But if yes maybe the battery when used the voltage drop and its will not give a suitable voltage because the resistance (i hope my idea clear)

Comment: @WillisLin yes i edit the question the led run on 700mA with typical voltage 1.7v and the maximum is 2v (and thanks you for the way)

Comment: @Pcp115 Right. With drained batteries (3 x 1.0V = 3V) you do not have enough voltage to supply Leds (3.6V) and resistor. You have to get one more battery or use converter.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický kinda understand-thank you

Comment: You must have a series resistor. Max current will be (Vbattmax-Vfmin)/R. Min current will be (Vbattmin-Vfmax)/R.

Comment: Why overheat the LEDs at their 700mA maximum allowed current? They need proper cooling for that. Can the little AAA battery cells produce that much current? 780mAh might be be only 20mA for 39 hours for a cheap AAA cell. Can you see the LEDs dimming fairly quickly?

Comment: @Audioguru Actually all the info about the led is from datasheet of it. It say that the led can work on typical 1.7v with 700ma current...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to play it safe, calculate the resistor using the highest battery voltage, and lowest LED voltage.  LEDs work fine when run at below their maximum rated current, so they will still work if your calculation was pessimistic.

If you want as much brightness as possible, then measure the actual battery voltage when under load, and the actual voltage across the LEDs when on.  Then re-calculate the resistor you need.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamental stuff:

- LEDs are not light bulbs but diodes. If you place diodes in series, their forward voltage adds up. So if these have 2V maximal V<sub>fwd</sub> then the supply must deliver at least 2+2 = 4V. Not a good idea.
- As you probably guessed, you need to add a current limiting resistor to the circuit or otherwise the LEDs and/or the batteries will get damaged or explode. This depends a lot on the specific battery chemistry. You will always damage LEDs  over time if you run more current through them than their specified maximum.

A sound design will rather look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn468M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- The battery pack consists of x number of cells to always yield a larger voltage than the diode forward voltage.
- R1 and R2 are calculated individually as per Ohm's Law: (V<sub>bat</sub> - V<sub>fwd</sub>) / I<sub>rated</sub>.
- Often you can pick a much lower current than the LED datasheet specifies as nominal. For example 20mA is common for SMD diodes, but you'd probably pick resistors suitable for around 5mA. Naturally depending on how much exact brightness matters in the application.